# Connector for Microsoft Dynamics: Setting owner to team in CRM (instead of user)

Tags: dynamics-crm, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

The Connector for Microsoft Dynamics between AX and CRM by default sets ownership of records in CRM to the integration user (or maps to specific users if that has been configured).

How do I make the connector set a team as owner in CRM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the connector set the owner in CRM to a team by doing the following:

1. Open Connector for Microsoft Dynamics.
2. Open the map you want to configure (e.g. *Customer Service to Account*).
3. Expand *Owning User* and remove the mapping.
4. Expand *Owning Team* and add the team name in *Dynamics Integration Key*, either as a constant or by mapping. Note that this should be the name of the team (not the Integration Key, even if you have configured the team entity for integration).
5. Save changes and wait for the integration to run.

In the end the map should look like the following:
[image: Owning team set, owning user removed]